# What is the difference between addEditor(user) and addEditor(emailAddress)?

Tags: google-apps-script

This is what [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#addEditor(User)) says about:

**addEditor(emailAddress):** Adds the given user to the list of editors for the protected sheet or range. This method does not automatically give the user permission to edit the spreadsheet itself.

**addEditor(user):** Adds the given user to the list of editors for the protected sheet or range. This method does not automatically give the user permission to edit the spreadsheet itself.

It's totally similar. What differentiates above 2 functions?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in the type of parameter expected; Google documents different types of parameters that can be passed to the same method separately (for example, see [`MailApp.sendEmail`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app) documentation which is in 4 parts).

The first version accepts a *string*, like "user@example.com". The second accepts an *object* of class [User](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user).

Examples:

```
var user = Session.getActiveUser(); // an object of class User
doc.addEditor(user);
```

versus

```
var user = Session.getActiveUser(); // an object of class User
var email = user.getEmail();        // a string containing email address
doc.addEditor(email);
```

Both are valid and have the same result, but they are different ways to use the method, because the parameters are of different types.